# Show Current Location on SecondViewController's MapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working on an app which has map functionalities.
I have two view controller's both have mapview , i am able to show current location on button click of `FirstViewController`. Now i want to show this location on the `SecondViewController` instead of `FirstViewController`. Have a look at my code of button click. Plz help

`

```
FirstViewController.m


 -(IBAction)btnMylLocation:(UIButton *)sender {


     CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude =  18.4897587, .longitude =  73.8202962};
     MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  1.00f, .longitudeDelta =  1.00f};
     MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
     [self.mapView setRegion:region];
     CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
     annotationCoord.latitude = 18.4897587;
     annotationCoord.longitude = 73.8202962;
     self.lblLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f ", annotationCoord.latitude];
     self.lblLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %f", annotationCoord.longitude];
     MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
     annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
     annotationPoint.title = @"Mindbowser";
     annotationPoint.subtitle = @"Pune Headquater's";
     [_mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];

  }
```

`

Comment: try after adding,  `_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES`

Comment: @RonakChaniyara plz elaborate

Comment: save latitude and longitude of A and pass it to B's mapview controller. U need to create a pin and pass co-ordinates accordingly